# Calculation of limit by using Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

I am supposed to calculate the following limit:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \propto }\frac{\pi}{n}(\sin \frac{\pi}{n}+\sin \frac{2\pi}{n}+...+\sin \frac{(n+1)\pi}{n})$$
Here is what I did:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \propto }\frac{\pi}{n}(\sin \frac{\pi}{n}+\sin \frac{2\pi}{n}+...+\sin \frac{(n+1)\pi}{n})=\lim_{n\rightarrow \propto }\frac{\pi}{n}\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}\sin \frac{i\pi}{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\sin xdx=\left [ -\cos x \right ]_{0}^{1}=0.459$$
Is it correct?
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the upper limit of integration be $\pi$?

Comment: @saulspatz Can you explain me why?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}{(n+1)\pi\over n}=\pi$

Comment: @saulspatz and everything else is correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $i/n=x$, then
the integral should be $L=\pi \int_{0}^{1} \sin \pi x dx \implies \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin y~ dy =2.$$